# I just need a little help to get my if statement to work

Tags: python-3.x

I am making a quiz which can work with different difficulties and it works fine. The only thing is that its like my code ignores my if statement at the bottom. even when the variable 'w' = 9, which is when i have answered 9 questions, it still doesn't print the statement it just continues looping.

```
import csv

w = 0
score = 0


global q
with open("Computing.txt", "r") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        dif_c = str(dif) +  " "
        if dif_c + str(q) + ")" in row[0]:
            print (row[0].split(dif_c)[1])
            print (row[1])
            if dif == 1:
                print (row[2])
                input10 = input("Answer 'a' or 'b': ")
            elif dif == 2:
                print(row[2] + "\n" + row[3])
                input10 = input("Answer 'a','b' or 'c': ")
            elif dif == 3:
                print(row[2] + "\n" + row[3] + "\n" + row[4])
                input10 = input("Answer 'a','b','c' or 'd': ")
            if input10 == row[dif + 2]:
                print("Correct")
                score = score + 1
                w = w + 1
            elif input10 != row[dif + 2]:
                print("Incorrect")
                w = w + 1

if w == 9:
    print("Game over")
    print("You got", r, "right out of 10")



while True:
    quiz()
```

this is all the quiz function and i defined w and score as 0 within the function which i know wouldnt work but i have no clue how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Your 'if' condition to check 'w == 9' should be inside the 'for' loop and you need to break out of the 'for' loop based on that condition. Otherwise it will continue to loop.

Currently your 'if' check is outside the 'for' loop.

So it should be changed to something like this:

```
import csv
w = 0 
score = 0
global q
with open("Computing.txt", "r") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        dif_c = str(dif) +  " "
        if dif_c + str(q) + ")" in row[0]:
            print (row[0].split(dif_c)[1])
            print (row[1])
            if dif == 1:
                print (row[2])
                input10 = input("Answer 'a' or 'b': ")
            elif dif == 2:
                print(row[2] + "\n" + row[3])
                input10 = input("Answer 'a','b' or 'c': ")
            elif dif == 3:
                print(row[2] + "\n" + row[3] + "\n" + row[4])
                input10 = input("Answer 'a','b','c' or 'd': ")
            if input10 == row[dif + 2]:
                print("Correct")
                score = score + 1
                w = w + 1
            elif input10 != row[dif + 2]:
                print("Incorrect")
                w = w + 1
        if w == 9:
            print("Game over")
            print("You got", r, "right out of 10")
            break
```